# Set innerHTML in javascript and get from C#

Tags: c#, innerhtml

I have two labels:

```
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

and I set innerHTML by javascript:

```
document.getElementById('Label1').innerHTML = position.lat();
document.getElementById('Label2').innerHTML = position.lng();
```

How I can get those labels values in codebehind? I try:

```
TextBox2.Text = Label1.Text;
```

**UPDATE**:I need to get pushpin location:

```
  <artem:GoogleMap ID="GoogleMap1" runat="server" 
    EnableMapTypeControl="False" MapType="Roadmap" >        
  </artem:GoogleMap>      
  <artem:GoogleMarkers ID="GoogleMarkers1" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="GoogleMap1" onclientpositionchanged="handlePositionChanged">
  </artem:GoogleMarkers> 
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var list = document.getElementById("Label1");
  function handlePositionChanged(sender, e) {
    printEvent("Position Changed", sender, e);
  }
  function printEvent(name, sender, e) {
    var position = e.latLng || sender.markers[e.index].getPosition();
    document.getElementById('Label1').innerHTML = position.lat();
    document.getElementById('Label2').innerHTML = position.lng();
  }
</script>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox2.Text = Label1.Text;// return value: Label
}
```

Comment: yes, your code seems to be correct. just confirm the values before assigning

Comment: No you cannot. To transfer data from client to server use input controls or Ajax.

Comment: What exactly is not working with your code? You should post a full example of what you tried and what happened so we can help you.

Comment: To have the updated data available to the page's code behind, you have to have the page post back first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot access the value on server side. You will have to use a hidden field for that:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden1" runat="server" />
```

The set the innerHtml value in the Hidden field by doing:

```
document.getElementById('<%= Hidden1.ClientID %>').value = position.lat();
```

You can then access it from server side by doing:

```
TextBox1.Text = Hidden1.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to do that with the `Label` control as when the page is posted back the content of labels are not posted to the server. You would need to make use of an input control of sorts. Probably a hidden input would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Take a hidden field like below

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnBody" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Then set its value in Jquery like below

```
<script>
function GetEmailID() {
    var bodyHtml = $("#editor").html();

    $("#hdnBody").val(bodyHtml);  
}
</script>
```

And in the code behind do this to get it

```
string body = hdnBody.Value;
```