# Set innerHTML in javascript and get from C# without using hidden field

Tags: asp.net

Label control Set innerHTML in javascript and get from C#, without using hidden field in asp.net.

Using the hidden field some one has done through this ([Set innerHTML in javascript and get from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217724/set-innerhtml-in-javascript-and-get-from-c-sharp)) but I donot want it. I want do without using the hidden field.

THanks
 PBN

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Though you can take a `textbox` and set it's `css` like `label` and try `read-only` property.